# How to change listrow background color upon selection in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a two listview placed side by side in row direction. Every list row shows a price of the product. User can select only one row in one listrow at a time upon selection list row background color should be changed to represent the selection of that row. Same for other list view too. The total of the both the listrow price should get added when user select their choice listrow from both the listview. How do I change the color of the listrow background to represent selection and add the prices respectively? Can I use TouchableHighlight for that?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to have each `ListView` store the key of the currently selected row (null if none are selected) in state, and pass a function in props to each row that allows it to set the parent's `CurrentlySelected` element to its own key. You can then use that function as `onPress` for one of the core `Touchable` components within the listview row.

If you are using the core `ListView` component, you should have the parent listview figure out when it is rendering the selected child in its `renderRow` function, and pass a boolean prop to let the child know it is selected. The child can decide what `styles` props to use based on the passed prop.